# How to dynamically generate and map a 2D image onto a mug?

Tags: graphics, 3d

we need to make these images on the fly on the server.
the image should warp onto a 2d image.

The result should look like this:

[image]

The input is a texture and this:

[image]

Comment: i found this : http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/
but this seems very old-school..

Comment: any sample input? if the input is texture and mug mask 2D image then it is a 2D problem. If you got the mug mesh then it is simple 3D rendering problem so what is the input?

Comment: both inputs are 2d images. whats the bests 2d solution?

Comment: without seeing the actual input images is hard to elaborate ...

Comment: Mug : https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1151/0394/products/white_large.png?v=1475010333

image: any flat 2D graphic.